# tag <video> não funciona em celulares android

Tags: jquery, html5

Estou desenvolvendo um site responsivo que possui um vídeo, quando acesso este site no celular o vídeo não é exibido, se inserir o vídeo através da tag  ele funciona.

Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Comment: Poderia postar seu código.

Comment: Sim claro, é uma simples tag de vídeo:

Comment: <video autoplay src="teste.mp4"></video>

Comment: Não sei uma solução conclusiva para isso, mas poderia olhar esse [artigo](https://www.broken-links.com/2010/07/08/making-html5-video-work-on-android-phones/) ?

Comment: Obrigado Everson! Vou ler o artigo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sem o código fica difícil, mas vamos lá..

1) Script para adicionar o arquivo de vídeo simples na página

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>HTML Video Tag Example</title>
</head>
<body>
<video width="320" height="240" controls="controls" autoplay="autoplay">
<source src="Yes Bank Advertisment.mp4" type="video/mp4">
<object data="" width="320" height="240">
<embed width="320" height="240" src="Yes Bank Advertisment.mp4">
</object>
</video>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: Figura 1]

**Figura 1:** Esta figura é a saída de vídeo simples de incorporação na página em HTML.

> Aqui vimos que o atributo de controle adiciona controles de vídeo,
>   como play, pause, e ajuste de volume. Também pode ser visto que o
>   vídeo está sendo reproduzido em uma região específica na página, razão
>   é que nós incluímos os atributos width e height para reprodução do
>   vídeo. Se a altura e largura são definidas, o espaço necessário para o
>   vídeo é reservado quando a página é carregada. No entanto, sem esses
>   atributos, navegador irá adaptando-se ou irá exibir a página completa.
>
> Não havia nenhum procedimento padrão para reproduzir vídeo em páginas
>   web. A maioria dos vídeos hoje são mostrados através de flash ou
>   vários plug-ins. No entanto, diferentes navegadores podem ter vários
>   plug-ins. Sem qualquer método padronizado torna-se difícil fornecer
>   vários plug-ins para navegadores diferentes. Como um remédio para
>   isso, o HTML5 define um novo elemento, que especifica uma forma padrão
>   para incorporar um vídeo/filme em uma página da web: o elemento
>   . Esta tag  é suportado por todos os principais
>   navegadores, tais como Internet explorer, Google Chrome, Safari, Opera
>   etc.
>
> A tag  foi proposta pelo Opera Software em fevereiro de 2007.
>   Opera também lançou uma compilação de visualização que foi mostrada na
>   mesma data, e um manifesto que chamou de video para se tornar primeira
>   classe de cidadão da web.

Comment: Isso é verdade, consumirá muita banda.

Comment: @ClaudioPerler , o Munir perguntou como inserir um vídeo no seu website e funcionando no mobile. Ele não informou se usa algum framework ou não, ou se vai consumir banda ou não. Caso ele queira entrar em mais detalhes no assunto, ele deverá fazer outro tipo de pergunta e utilizar algum framework que fica muito mais fácil a inserção de um vídeo responsivo, sem consumo de tanta banda.

Comment: Thiago, realmente eu não especifiquei utilização de framework ou consumo de banda, agradeço pelo auxilio!